# Saving hashmap at different times

Tags: hashmap

my question is:
I'm trying to save the values of properties to a hashmap. Every time I click, it will save a new set of variables to my hashmap, but when I go to output the saved variables, it will only display the newly saved variables even though I have the hashMap loop though. Why is this?

I have

```
Map<Boolean, Integer> property = new HashMap<Boolean, Integer>();
```

As a global variable

This is how I save the variables to my Hashmap

```
property.put(m.turn, tempBoard.current.position);
```

This happens every time I click a certain image after a series of events happen, though they don't affect the Hashmap

I then return back to the same class that the hashmap is created in, but in a different procedure. The code I use to loop though the hashmap is:

```
for (Map.Entry<Boolean, Integer> entry : property.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

This only outputs the newly saved variables to the hashmap, not any of the other save variables.

To be honest with you, I've been searching google, trying to find the reason why it won't start at the beginning of the save variables. I can't find anything that resembles my problem because every other example, they save their variables to the hashmap all at the same time; never at different times or in between event events.

Any help is appreciated, and sorry for how weird this post is worded. I'm not sure how to explain it any better :)

Comment: you are using Boolean as key , thus , boolean only has 2 value true / false. New value will replace old value when same key.

Comment: Oh my, I can't believe it was that simple, thank you very much! haha I guess that's what happens when you're just starting how to code :D

Answer (score 0):

How are supposed to store more than 2 values in hashmap?
I think you need to understand how hashmap works, In hashmap you store a VALUE against a UNIQUE key, and the method put will alwaysa replace old value of the key with new value passed, if you use some already added key, otherwise it will add this value against given key.
Now you just need to figure how would you store all values and which type of Key you want to use.
Have a look at this link for details of HashMap
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html